# Referencing to Class Library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make my main app, which is a web api using MVC5, to reference to my Model, Business Layers. When referencing I get the following error

[image]

This is my folder structure

[image]

This is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I have Visual Studio Community 2015, and not sure how to fix this.

This is what my properties for my main project show

[image]

Comment: what is the framework version set for your class library and MVC app

Comment: The target framework for my model is .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Properties -> Application tab of your class library and MVC app

Comment: for web api, check Properties -> Build tab

Comment: I should say its a web api, not MVC, under Cann->Proerties-Build I only see configuration Active(debug), platform active (any cpu) I dont see MVC app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project.json file, change this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

To this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx452": { }
},
```

The class libraries that you've created are not [portable class libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx), and as such are not compatible with DNXCORE50, which is a cross-platform framework.

Comment: Thank you, this is an ackward default behavior